# Testing MVC Controller Action from raw POST data

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have a 3rd party vendor I want to integrate with my web site. I have a sample of the POST data they will be sending to me and I want to be able to write a unit test to verify I can process it from my controller action.

Ideally I could have a unit test that loads the raw POST data from a file and I can invoke the action using that as input.

What is the best approach? Or perhaps a testing framework for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a testing framework such as `NUnit`, then do something like:

```
    [Test]
    public void CanProcessThirdPartyData(string data)
    {
                var success = controller.ProcessData(data):
                if (success) {
                    Assert.Pass();
                }
    }
```

Comment: ProcessData would your controller method that will process the data.  The idea here is that you create a stub of your controller and invoke the action you will use to process the vendors data.

Comment: I'd rather not change my Controller to enable a testing scenario. I'm hoping for something more akin to invoking the HTTP pipeline from a unit test

Comment: P.S. I had intended to use something stronger than string as the types on my actions. Perhaps I should reconsider though

Comment: @Schneider you wouldn't have to.  You could create a new class to mimic the functionality that will process the third party data (Or create a stub like I previously mentioned). The logic will be the same between this class and your controller.